# Nested query in squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, select, squeel

Short version: How do I write this query in squeel?

```
SELECT OneTable.*, my_count
FROM   OneTable JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT one_id, count(*) AS my_count
  FROM   AnotherTable
  GROUP BY one_id
) counts
ON OneTable.id=counts.one_id
```

---

Long version: [rocket_tag](https://github.com/bradphelan/rocket_tag) is a gem that adds simple tagging to models. It adds a method `tagged_with`. Supposing my model is `User`, with an id and name, I could invoke `User.tagged_with ['admin','sales']`. Internally it uses this squeel code:

```
select{count(~id).as(tags_count)}
.select("#{self.table_name}.*").
joins{tags}.
where{tags.name.in(my{tags_list})}.
group{~id}
```

Which generates this query:

```
SELECT count(users.id) AS tags_count, users.*
  FROM users INNER JOIN taggings
    ON taggings.taggable_id = users.id
   AND taggings.taggable_type = 'User'
  INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
  WHERE tags.name IN ('admin','sales')
  GROUP BY users.id
```

Some RDBMSs are happy with this, but postgres complains:

```
ERROR: column "users.name" must appear in the GROUP BY
clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I believe a more agreeable way to write the query would be:

```
SELECT users.*, tags_count FROM users INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT taggable_id, count(*) AS tags_count
    FROM taggings INNER JOIN tags
      ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
    WHERE tags.name IN ('admin','sales')
    GROUP BY taggable_id
  ) tag_counts
  ON users.id = tag_counts.taggable_id
```

Is there any way to express this using squeel?

Comment: What is you PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't know about Squeel, but the error you see could be fixed by upgrading PostgreSQL.

> Some RDBMSs are happy with this, but postgres complains:
>
> ERROR: column "users.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

Starting with PostgreSQL 9.1, once you list a primary key in the GROUP BY you can skip additional columns for this table and still use them in the SELECT list. The [release notes for version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-1.html) tell us:

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the GROUP BY clause

---

BTW, your alternative query can be simplified, an additional `DISTINCT` would be redundant.

```
SELECT o.*, c.my_count
FROM   onetable o
JOIN (
  SELECT one_id, count(*) AS my_count
  FROM   anothertable
  GROUP  BY one_id
) c ON o.id = counts.one_id
```

Comment: That's really good to know, thanks! Unfortunately I'm running the application on heroku, so an upgrade from 8.3 to 9.1 will cost me at least $200 a month, but if the problem is specific to old versions of postgres then I guess I will accept that I have to work around with find_by_sql. I'm still curious though if squeel can be used for this sort of query.

Comment: @dslh: [Heroku Labs already offers 9.1](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-heroku-shared-postgresql). You may be interested.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question but it did solve my problem. I guess I was asking the wrong question. Thanks very much!