# Count by association: syntax error at or near "AS"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to order a group of TV shows by how many times an actor has been on.  I followed some other stack overflow questions asking the same question but I'm getting an error I don't see mentioned anywhere.

```
 Show.joins(:contributions)
  .select('show.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count')
  .where('contributions.role_id = 2')
  .where('contributions.person_id IN (?)', self.id)
  .order('guest_count desc')
```

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 1: SELECT
>   COUNT(show.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_co...

Output:

```
: SELECT COUNT(COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count, show.*) FROM
"show" INNER JOIN "episodes" ON "episodes"."show" = "show"."id" 
INNER JOIN "contributions" ON "contributions"."episode_id" = 
"episodes"."id" WHERE (contributions.role_id = 2) AND 
(contributions.person_id IN (42))
```

This is the stack overflow I've been following: [Rails 3 ActiveRecord: Order by count on association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association?rq=1)

Comment: Can you post the results of the sql explain?

Comment: good idea, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: You won't get an `explain` result from this  because it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like arel isn't setting up your SQL statement correctly. Try reversing the conditions in the select.

```
.select('COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count, show.*')
```

Maybe that will help arel out.

EDIT:

You also have a second problem. You're trying to use an aggregate function but you're not indicated which columns you want to group by. When using the aggregate don't use `show.*` and instead list the columns you want to select. After, use the `group` method to list the columns so they can be included in the aggregate query.

EDIT 2:

Can you just use something like:

```
shows = Show.includes(:contributions).all
```

and access the counts with:

```
shows.first.contributions.count
```

or is this a performance issue you're optimizing?

Comment: For a show like 'Game of Thrones' I want a table of the most frequent characters listed in order (# of times they've been on, in this case a 'contribution').

Comment: your tip about reversing the order (putting the COUNT() first) fixed my issue after an upgrade from rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

The raw SQL could look like this:

```
SELECT s.*, x.ct
FROM   shows s
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT e.show, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   episodes e
   JOIN   contributions c ON e.id = c.episode_id
   WHERE  c.role_id = 2
   AND    c.person_id = ?  -- self.id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) x ON s.id = x.show
ORDER  BY x.ct DESC NULLS LAST;
```

This includes shows without any appearances of the person, but takes care to sort those last. To exclude those shows use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Consider:

- [GroupingError: ERROR: column " " must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660396/groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-i/29661654#29661654)
- [Nested query in squeel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763538/nested-query-in-squeel/9766436#9766436)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Answer (score -1):

You have to change `show` tables into `shows`:

```
Show.joins(:contributions)
  .select('shows.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count')
  .where('contributions.role_id = 2')
  .where('contributions.person_id IN (?)', self.id)
  .group("shows.id")
  .order('guest_count desc')
```

Comment: same error:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(show.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_co...
                                                         ^
: SELECT COUNT(show.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count) FROM "show" INNER JOIN "episodes" ON "episodes"."show_id" = "show"."id" INNER JOIN "contributions" ON "contributions"."episode_id" = "episodes"."id" WHERE (contributions.role_id = 2) AND (contributions.person_id IN (42))

:(

Comment: Based on your error, you didn't change your `show` into `shows` in your select query. Try it again. :)

Comment: I thought I did.  I just tried again after restarting and I'm getting a different error :)

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "shows.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT shows.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count FR...
               ^
: SELECT shows.*, COUNT(contributions.id) AS guest_count FROM "shows" INNER JOIN "episodes" ON "episodes"."show_id" = "shows"."id" INNER JOIN "contributions" ON "contributions"."episode_id" = "episodes"."id" WHERE (contributions.role_id = 2) AND (contributions.person_id IN (42))  ORDER BY guest_count desc

Comment: It's okay. I thought, Postgres needs `group_by` to count your guest_count.   I will update it later.